# How to mathematically describe lag measured from cross correlation

Tags: mathematical-modeling

In MATLAB, this is the function used to measure `lag` using `cross-correlation`:

```
[acor,lag] = xcorr(s2,s1);
[~,I] = max(abs(acor));
lagDiff = lag(I)
timeDiff = lagDiff/Fs
```

where $s1$ and $s2$ are the signals, $acor$ is the cross-correlation coefficent $r$, $I$ is the coordination of $lag$ at which the maximum cross correlation occurs

Can somebody help me to explain $lagDiff$ in mathematical form?

Comment: it is the lag at which the maximum cross correlation occurs

Comment: @michaelStachowsky edited based on your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \langle x_1, \cdots x_n\rangle$ be the vector of cross correlations, where the subscript indicates the lag - you may suitable turn this into a time value if you know the time step of your original data.  We can define the lag vector much more simply: $L = \langle 1, 2, ..., n \rangle$, and let $L_i$ be the $i^{th}$ component.

Then $I = \underset{i}{\operatorname{argmax}}X$

Your "lagDiff" is just $L_{I}$.

**EDIT**: Explaining some notation in general

The "argmax" operation is related to finding a maximum.  Using our above example,

$M = \underset{i}{\operatorname{max}}X$ means: "search through all of the $x_i$ components of $X$, and find the biggest one".  Literally: find the maximum of $X$.  $M$ will be the maximum value we've found.

Then $I = \underset{i}{\operatorname{argmax}}X$ means "search through all of the $x_i$ components of $X$, and find the biggest one.  We aren't interested in knowing what that is.  Instead, we want to know the index at which it occurs."  That index is stored in I.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I need further clarification between the relationship between $I$ and $ i$ using the `argmax` (I am still learning about math symbols). Is argmax $i$ means the index $i-th$ of where $X$ is max. To put this simply, is $i$ here automatically refers to an index?

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully it explains a bit more